# how to install web.py on windows

Tags: python, web.py

I've followed the tutorial on the official web.y website and I've tried running `python setup.py install` through the command prompt but I keep getting this error:

" "python" is not recognized as an internal or external command "

I also tried double clicking setup.py but that doesn't seem to work either

so I don't know what I'm doing wrong

note that I've never used the command prompt before so I don't know anything about it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your going to need to use the command prompt, but it's super simple so don't be scared. You need to add python to your path. Look at this tutorial:
http://www.varunpant.com/posts/how-to-setup-easy_install-on-windows

Then just run:

```
easy_install web.py
```

In your terminal (cmd.exe) to install web.py! Good luck!

Comment: I've followed that tutorial and I can't even get `echo %PYTHON_HOME%;` to tell me the path, it just says `%PYTHON_HOME%;`

Comment: I've figured out what I was doing wrong, I was putting them in user variables instead of system variables, it's working now, thanks!

Comment: @Mranth0ny62 Not a problem! Have a great time doing some web.py!

Answer (score 0):

- Open a windows command prompt (start, run, cmd)
- Navigate to your Python directory (e.g. `pushd %programfiles(x86)%\python27`).  This step is only required if python's directory is not included in your `path` environment variable.
- run the following: `python -m pip install -U pip web.py`

You should see something like the below; after which `web.py` has been installed.

```
c:\PROGRA~2\python27>python -m pip install -U pip web.py
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\progra~2\python27\lib\site-packages
Collecting web.py
  Downloading web.py-0.38.tar.gz (91kB)
    100% |################################| 92kB 861kB/s
Installing collected packages: web.py
  Running setup.py install for web.py ... done
Successfully installed web.py-0.38
```

This is based on the method used for installing setuptools referenced here: https://packaging.python.org/installing/.  I recommend this way over using setuptools, since to use that you have to first install it, which is self-defeating.